# When I'm try to use redis on my project laravel 6.x it show this error message

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-6

ERROR:

> Please remove or rename the Redis facade alias in your "app" configuration file in order to avoid collision with the PHP Redis extension

[image]

I put this code on my `cache.php`

`'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'redis'),`

And those code in my controller:

```
$data['posts']   = cache('posts',function(){
      Post::with('user')
          ->select('title', 'created_at', 'user_id', 'thumbnail_path', 'content')
          ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
          ->take(50)
          ->get();
});
```

Answer (score 23):

Firstly, you need to make sure you have actually installed predis using composer by running this in your terminal:
`composer require predis/predis`

And then you need to make sure that your have this set in your .env file
`REDIS_CLIENT=predis`

This is covered in the docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/redis

Comment: Did you cleared the cache? Try php artisan config:clear && php artisan config:cache && php artisan cache:clear

Answer (score 1):

I got this error message when I hosted my Laravel app on [cloudways.com](http://cloudways.com/). I fixed it by installing Redis and Supervisord from the server 'Settings & Packages' page.